# Using separate predefined Validation Set with sklearn GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm running a GridSearchCV (Grid Search Cross Validation) from the Sklearn Library on a RandomForestClassifier. 
I want to use a train/validation/test split that I already obtained and previously saved on disk on separate numpy arrays (i.e., for compatibility on some tests I'll have to do with other algorithms on the same split).

I can't find a way to use my separate Validation Set with GridSearchCV. The only workaround I found is to use PredefinedSplit on a new numpy array where I concatenate the original train and validation arrays I loaded from saved files.

```
ts_train = extractPlainTable(np.load('TimeSeries/train_x%d_30.npy' % i),s)
ts_val = extractPlainTable(np.load('TimeSeries/validation_x%d_20.npy' % i),s)
ts_test = extractPlainTable(np.load('TimeSeries/test_x%d_30.npy' % i),s)


labels_train = np.load('ground_truth/train_y%d_30.npy' % i)
labels_val = np.load('ground_truth/validation_y%d_20.npy' % i)
labels_test = np.load('ground_truth/test_y%d_30.npy' % i)

clf =  RandomForestClassifier()

merged_ts = np.concatenate((ts_train,ts_val),axis=0)
merged_labels = np.concatenate((labels_train,labels_val),axis=0)
mytestfold = []
for i in range(len(ts_train)):
    mytestfold.append(-1)
for i in range(len(ts_val)):
    mytestfold.append(0)


ps = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=mytestfold)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid,cv=ps)
grid_search.fit(merged_ts, merged_labels)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an iterable with a single pair of train/val indices.

```
split = [(range(len(ts_train)), range(len(ts_train), len(ts_train) + len(ts_val)))]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid, cv=split)
grid_search.fit(merged_ts, merged_labels)
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't avoid creating the merged version (that is what I was trying to do :) )